# Materialized view only for covering index

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views, covering-index

Given the following table `car_year` of car model's year:

```
| id | maker |      model | year |
----------------------------------
|  6 |  Audi |    Allroad | 2001 |
| 12 |  Audi |         A8 | 2008 |
| 14 |  Ford |    Mustang | 1996 |
| 15 | Honda |      Civic | 2000 |
| 19 | Honda |    Insight | 2000 |
| 22 |  Ford |       F150 | 2009 |
| 24 | Honda |     Accord | 2000 |
| 28 |  Ford |       F150 | 2007 |
| 34 |  Audi |         S8 | 2002 |
| 48 |  Ford | Expedition | 2011 |
| 62 |  Ford |     Escort | 2004 |
| 81 |  Ford |   Explorer | 2007 |
| 84 |  Ford |     Escape | 2006 |
| 93 | Honda |     Accord | 1995 |
```

I would like to have a covering index for the "earliest model of a maker".
My solution is to create a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW earliest AS
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(maker) maker, model
    FROM car_year
    ORDER BY maker, year
```

And then a covering index over it:

```
CREATE INDEX earliest_index ON earliest(maker) INCLUDE (model);
```

It works! But the materialized views is **useless** (for my usage) because I will only use the  the covering index.
Am I missing a more elegant solution, or a (Postgre)SQL feature that I don't know about ?

Comment: Why not apply the covering index to the base table instead?

Comment: I only need the *earliest* model, not all models for a maker. If I create the index on the base table, `SELECT model FROM car_year WHERE maker = 'ford'` will return 7 rows, when it should only return 1 with "Mustang".

Comment: Use ```DISTINCT```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you are asking for an “index organized table” (or index organized materialized view in that case), that is a table that is really an index. Then you wouldn't have to waste twice the storage, once for the table that you never use, and once for the index, on which you want to perform index-only scans.

The answer is that such “index organized tables” don't exist in PostgreSQL.